# device not showing on adb devices. Hard brick Moto g 9 play

Tags: android, adb, motorola

my moto g9 play had a hard brick, i restored fastboot mode, but cant connect to adb

i installed the qualcomm drivers, then i made a blank flash using a file called blankflash_caprip_SRC32.56, which is intended for Moto g30, but was the only way to restore fastboot on my device. I tried with blankflash_guamp_RPX31.Q2-58-16, the proper version to moto g9 and it did nothing. Now my phone starts on fastboot mode, being recognized as moto g30 i think. Now i need to install recovery, but when i use minimal adb & fastboot, my device doesnt appear in adb devices list

Comment: A device that is in fastboot mode will never ever be usable via adb. Fastboot mode requires fastboot drivers and fastboot executable.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the answer. Do you know how I should proceed? I need to install TWRP on my device, but I don't have a recovery. I apologize if I'm not clear about some terms, as I'm not familiar with this process.
When i try to install via fasboot with minimal fastboot and adb tool, using this code: "fastboot flash recovery twrp.img" it shows me the following error :
(bootloader) invalid partition name recovery

Comment: Modern devices have two the system+recovery two times for seamless updates, so the recovery partition names are usually `recovery_a`and `recovery_b`.

Comment: so i should use the code like this?  fastboot flash recovery_a twrp.img?